# Thread can't connect using named pipes when main process can; works with username password

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I'm using named pipes to connect to a database using EF Code First. It works fine in normal page request lifecycles.

I'm spawning a separate thread to send a batch of emails. That thread is passed a connection string (named pipe) and creates a new dbcontext using that connection string. But for some reason it cannot connect:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.
```

If I switch the connection string to username password form, the thread works fine.

Anyone know why named pipes are fine in normal page execution but not a thread?

Our staging server is the only non-live server we use named pipes on so it's been hard to track this down, but it is erroring on new DbContext.

Sample code:

```
        var contextConnectionString = dataAccessLayer.ConnectionString;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Errors on the next line I think
            using (var threadSafeDataAccessLayer = new PaladinContext(contextConnectionString))
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Just in case it's something I'm doing wrong in the connection string, here's an idea of the one that fails:

```
Data Source=[SERVERNAME]\[INSTANCE_NAME]; Initial Catalog=[correct db name];Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

And one that succeeds:

```
Data Source=[full url to server]; Initial Catalog=[correct db name]; User Id=[user]; Password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

Just to reiterate, the connection string only fails in the spawned thread. It's the same one I'm using everywhere else.

[Update]
In the working connection string, changing Data Source=[SERVERNAME][INSTANCE_NAME] doesn't stop it working. So that's also fine to use. Didn't want that being a red herring.